# What is the definition of the absolute convergence of an infinite product $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3)\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

For  an infinite product $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3)\cdots$,

1. whats the definition of convergence and absolute convergence?
2. Why the absolute convergence corresponding to the absolute convergence of sum of an infinite series $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$?
3. If the infinite product absolutely convergent, does it mean it is convergent?
4. If the sum of $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$ convergent, does it mean the corresponding product convergent?

I know the meaning of the convergent and absolute convergent of an infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$, it can be understand very intuitively.

Comment: We could say that $\displaystyle\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)$ converges absolutely if and only if $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ln(1+a_n)$ converges absolutely.

Comment: @This is the definition? what about other questions?

Comment: For 3, the answer is no, take $a_k=1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @wythagoras if $a_k=1$, the product not absolutely convergent.

Comment: @buzhidao Never mind, I thought you meant if the product $a_1a_2a_3a_4...$ is convergent.

Comment: @wythagoras if all $a_k=1$, $a_1a_2a_3\cdots$ is convergent, it also absolute convergent because \sum_{n} \log a_n absolute convergent.  See the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You may know that convergence of products is *not* defined just in terms of "limit of partial products exists", for example $\prod \frac 1n$ is by definition not convergent, even though the partial products converge to $0$. Instead the definition is such that there may be finitely many factors $=0$ and for the remaining factors the sum of the logs is convergent. If we get rid of the logarithm, this gives us the direct definition:

> $\prod x_n$ is said to be convergent if there exists $N$ such that the sequence of partial products $\prod_{n=N}^Mx_n$ converges to a nonzero(!) limit as $M\to\infty$.

This is also why absolut convergence of $\prod (1+a_n)$  infinite products is defined as absolute convergence of $\sum\ln(a+a_n)$ (ignoring the possibly finitely many factors $=0$ here). (After all, the *signs* of the factors themselves cannot play a role: they must converge to $+1$, hence there can only be finitely many negative factors.) As a consequence, we have the same properties as with sums, i.e., absolute convergence implies that the order of factors does not matter.

Now assume $\sum \ln(1+a_n)$ is convergent. Then specifically $a_n\to 0$. As $\ln(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$ we see that the behaviour of $\sum \ln(1+a_n)$ is essentially the same as that of $\sum a_n$. Therefore the convergence/absolute convergence of $\prod(1+a_n)$ can be related to convergence/absolute convergence of $\sum a_n$.